# jQuery treeview highlight selected

Tags: jquery, treeview, highlighting

Is highlighting the selected item supported in jQuery treeview?  Can you point me at sample code demonstrating this?

Answer (score 0):

yes
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview/treeview#options
persist

Answer (score 0):

The `persist` option persists the tree state in cookies or the page location.

If set to "location", looks for the anchor that matches location.href and activates that part of the treeview it. Great for href-based state-saving.

If set to "cookie", saves the state of the tree on each click to a cookie and restores that state on page load.

The following code sample enables the navigation option for this treeview, matching the active treeview element to location.href

```
$(".selector").treeview({
   persist: "location"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To **visually** highlight the selected item, you can add a `$('selector').click()` method to the base list elements that you build the JQuery Treeview on.

When that list element is clicked, your click function will be fired. You can then, in this function, change the CSS class of the selected element to highlight it.